# applewallet completeaddpaymentpass doesnt take into account the attribute :ephemeralPublicKey

Tags: react-native, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, capacitor

i use @awesome-cordova-plugins/apple-wallet for apple transaction process in my react native ionic capacitor application .
in my function as

```
    const completeAddPaymentPass = async (data: any): Promise<string> => {
      const base64EncodedData = {
        activationData: encodeToBase64(data.activationData),
        encryptedPassData: encodeToBase64(data.encryptedPassData),
        ephemeralPublicKey: encodeToBase64(data.ephemeralPublicKey),
      };
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('appleWallet.completeAddPaymentPass before...');
        appleWallet
          .completeAddPaymentPass(base64EncodedData)
          .then((res: string) => {
            console.log(
              'appleWallet.completeAddPaymentPass successfully...',
              JSON.stringify(res),
            );
            resolve(res);
          })
          .catch((error: any) => {
            console.error('Error: appleWallet.completeAddPaymentPass', error);
            reject(error);
          });
      });
    };
```

the AppleWallet.completeAddPaymentPass accept only wrappedKey (RSA encryption format), i use ECC encryption, i want use ephemeralPublicKey attribute in function parameter intead wrappedKey.

How can i do ?